# Mounting an S3 bucket to an EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I've looked at several tutorials on mounting S3 buckets using S3fs, but I sense these are geared towards key-based authentication.  Right now if I "aws s3 ls" (or use other "aws s3 ls bucketname") I can see a lot of directories and within those directories due to the instance profile (IAM).  Thus since I already have access and could technically cp using the AWS CLI,  I want to "mount" one of those directories so that when I'm accessing my EC2 instance remotely via an sftp program, or via remote python interpreter, that S3 bucket and all it's contents appear just as another directory attached to the system.

Is this possible?  If so what set of commands can I run to mount the S3 bucket that I already have access to via AWS CLI commands so that it acts as just another directory on the local system.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "but I sense these are geared towards key-based authentication"? And how does/would that cause issues for you?

Comment: **Side-note:** Amazon is an object storage service, not a filesystem. It is not recommended to "mount" Amazon S3 as a drive -- especially in Production systems. It is more reliable to access Amazon S3 via API calls.

Comment: @Marcin that link takes me to an IAM user signin page.  Is that the correct link?

Comment: @jarmod I got the impression through comments on SO about s3fs that it wasn't the ideal option to do what I wanted, but it was hard for me to nail down exactly what other options there were during fact-finding.  I spent a day searching and trying things before finally posting on here just because I still wasn't sure if I was going down the best path for what I wanted.

Comment: Sorry, the correct link: https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse#examples

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Your comment is one of the main reasons I ask such questions here.  I quickly watched a video on this to understand the difference, but i'm not sure how this would change the way I should interact with the stored objects?  I'm still ultimately trying to work with S3 buckets as a permanent storage location, and using Python.  In my mind Filezilla and python "os"-type Python functions are easy for me to work with -- how are the API calls better (and what API are you referring to?).

Comment: When using S3, applications should specifically store and retrieve data in S3 via API calls (for Python, using [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html)). This can be hard for apps that expect everything to be in a local filesystem, but it is the more resilient way to use S3. Behind-the-scenes, s3fs uses these API calls, but "presents" S3 as a filesystem. This can give rise to potential issues, especially when files are being added/updated quickly. See: [Amazon S3 examples](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-examples.html)

Answer (score 1):

This question addresses using instance profile credentials with s3fs instead of access keys:
[s3fs with aws ec2 instance and using instance profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43793288/s3fs-with-aws-ec2-instance-and-using-instance-profiles)

Comment: Thanks -- I suppose this is probably the answer, but when I put s3fs s3://my_bucket_name /PATHtoLocalMount fuse _netdev,iam_role=nameofiamrolenoquotes into etc/fstab and rebooted, I couldn't connect to my instance :o.  I tried without the "s3://" and it didn't mount anything.  Wonder what i might be doing wrong.

Comment: I just tried this on a fresh instance and haven't been able to get it to work yet either. Some things you can look at for help: look for errors in /var/log/syslog. Also, try mounting it with the s3fs command before going the fstab route to save the reboots with each change. If you can get it to work with the command and not in fstab, then you can try with a startup script. See steps 7 and 8 here for example of mounting: https://medium.com/tensult/aws-how-to-mount-s3-bucket-using-iam-role-on-ec2-linux-instance-ad2afd4513ef

Answer (score 0):

It you are on Debian you can use these commands to get setup:

```
cd ~/;
sudo apt-get install s3fs;
echo ACCESS_KEY:SECRET_KEY > ~/.passwd-s3fs;
# confirm entry was added
cat ~/.passwd-s3fs;
chmod 600 .passwd-s3fs;
mkdir ~/BUCKETNAME-s3-drive;
s3fs BUCKETNAME ~/BUCKETNAME-s3-drive;
```

Fully explained here - https://impressto.net/connect-to-s3-from-your-local-file-system/